# Query for differences between columns

Tags: sql-server, difference

I have this sample data:

| ID | Color | Scent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Red | Stinky |
| 1 | Yellow | Flower-like |
| 1 | Green | Neutral |
| 2 | Blue | Stinky |
| 2 | Blue | Flower-like |
| 2 | Blue | Flower-like |

There are mutiple rows pertaining to the single ID.

The result I want is to have something like this:

| ID | Remarks |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Different colors, different scents |
| 2 | Different scents |

The same value for the rows is the ID, and if there are any difference in that column (for example, with ID 2, the scents are flower-like and stinky) make a remark "Different scents"

I'm not yet a pro, so I don't know if it's possible. I'm thinking of selecting distinct IDs, case when, and joins, but when doing the query, I'm stuck on what should be the next step.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Seems you can use a combination of `CONCAT_WS` (assuming you're on a fully supported version of SQL Server, as you don't state otherwise), `CASE` and  `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       CONCAT_WS(', ', CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Colour) > 1 THEN 'Different Colours' END,
                       CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Scent) > 1 THEN 'Different Scents' END) AS Remarks
FROM(VALUES(1,'Red','Stinky'),
           (1,'Yellow','Flower-like'),
           (1,'Green','Neutral'),
           (2,'Blue','Stinky'),
           (2,'Blue','Flower-like'),
           (2,'Blue','Flower-like'))V(ID, Colour, Scent)
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: `CASE WHEN MIN(Colour) <> MAX(Colour)` is probably more efficient as it doesn't require a sort over `Colour`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the idea :) I will get back to you once I've done some querying